# Как уменьшить расход памяти

Tags: python, память

Я проверяю уникальность строк, для этого я делаю из них множество(set) и потом вычисляю его длину, однако расход памяти в этом случае вдвое больше чем нужно. Как мне его сократить?

```
N = int(input())
a = [[(i) for i in input().split()] for _ in range(N)]
a1 = set([item for sublist in a for item in sublist])
print(len(a1))
```

Comment: Приведите точную формулировку и короткий пример входных данных. Пока не вполне ясно - для чего, например, делается split

Comment: @MBo Пример ввода данных: 8
вк
рефераты
вк
ок
одноклассники
яндекс
вконтакте
ок
Вывод :6 Да, split тут лишний - каждая строка (ок вк и т.д.) начинается с новой строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
set([item for sublist in a for item in sublist])
```

попробуйте заменить на

```py
{item for sublist in a for item in sublist}
```

это как минимум позволит не создавать лишний промежуточный список

В вашем случае скорее всего достаточно будет сделать

```py
a1 = {input() for _ in range(int(input()))}
```

Если предполагать, что уникальные хеши соответствуют уникальным значениям

```py
input()
print(len(set(map(hash, sys.stdin))))
```

Comment: Все равно выдает превышение объема памяти почти в 2 раза. У меня было две идеи по поводу ускорения кода: использовать хеш-функцию и считывать не в отдельный список a, а сразу во множество a1. Скажите, пожалуйста, насколько это имеет смысл?Да и добавлю - объем уникальных строк от 5000 до 10000

Comment: Превышение скорее всего происходит при разбиении строки на подстроки, если это какой-нибудь `acmp.ru`, это типичное узкое место. В множество строки не копируются, только ссылки (и хеши) на них, а вот строка целиком и список подстрок в какой-то момент существуют в памяти одновременно. выход - подгружать строку по кускам и разбивать вручную, но это сильно ударит по производительности. еще вариант - `re.finditer` - минус еще один список. в памяти только строка и сет, но он тоже медленный

Comment: Да, это олимпиадная задача. Не могли бы Вы привести пример кода, когда строка подгружается по кускам и разбивается вручную на примере этой задачи. Запас по производительности достаточно большой

Comment: @Timur Shleminov Приведите точное условие или ссылку на задачу.

Comment: @TimurShleminov обновил решение

Comment: @MBo Найдите количество уникальных строк при условии ограничения по времени 5 секунд и по памяти 5 Mb. В первой строке указанно число - количество строк. В каждой последующей строке вводится n-ная строка. Нужно найти среди них количество уникальных строк.Длина каждого запроса не превосходит 1000 символов

Comment: количество строк как ограничено?

Comment: Если верить заданию, ничего на подстроки разбивать не надо. в каждой строке воода - новое значение.

Comment: @extm объем памяти сократился до 6 Mb на 2 тесте, но порог 5 Mb

Comment: @MBo Да, количество строк меньше 500000

Comment: ну тогда хеширование - вполне вариант. встроенная функция hash() поможет. только равенство хэшей не гарантирует равенство значений, так что либо использовать несколько алгоритмов хеширования для повышения шансов, либо проходить входные данные дважды: первый раз находить повторяющиеся хеши, второй - выяснять повторяются ли соответсвующие им строки.

Comment: Таким образом, судя по ограничениям, все подряд строки хранить нельзя, хэши+уникальные строки (т.е. словарь) - можно. Что такое в данном случае "запрос"?

Comment: @extrn Да, это, наверное, выход. Если Вас не затруднит, напишите, как будет выглядеть алгоритм с hash функцией, пожалуйста

Comment: @MBo запрос в данном случае - это строка, которая оценивается на уникальность

Answer (score 0):

А если без генераторов?

```
my_set = set()

N = int(input())
for _ in range(N):
    for i in input().split():
        my_set.add(i)

print(len(my_set))
```

А если добавить сборку мусора на каждой итерации строки?

```
import gc

my_set = set()

N = int(input())
for _ in range(N):
    for i in input().split():
        my_set.add(i)

    gc.collect()

print(len(my_set))
```

Comment: Не проходит по объему памяти

Comment: @TimurShleminov, обновил ответ

Comment: с использованием сборки мусора решение выходит за пределы допустимого времени